# How to slice reference video in FFmpeg filtering

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to check vmaf results of slice of reference video (that also pass the scaling)

This is how I created the file I want to check:

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -i <reference video> -ss 00:00:30 -t 00:01:00 -c:v libx265 -preset superfast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -s 1280x720 <newFile>
```

Now I want to check it's vmaf score, this is how I handle the scaling:

```
 ffmpeg -i <newFile> -i <reference file> -filter_complex [0:v]scale=1920:1080:flags=bicubic[main];[main][1:v]libvmaf=model_path=<libvmaf path>:log_path=VMAF.txt -f null -
```

How do I add to the filter that I want it to compare only to slice of the reference file (start at -ss  during -t )?

Answer (score 0):

You should also crop the reference video  without re-encoding it so you can't use `-ss` or `-t` options. To do it, try with  `trim` filter.

```sh
ffmpeg -i <newFile> -i <reference> -filter_complex "[1:v]trim=start=30,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ref];[0:v]scale=1920:1080:flags=bicubic[main];[main][ref]libvmaf=model_path=<libvmaf path>:log_path=VMAF.txt -f null -
```

This will work only if your videos were originally aligned. If not, the challenge is a bit more complex. You can check here some details about syncing main and ref videos for vmaf computation.

- [easyVmaf](https://github.com/gdavila/easyVmaf)
- [Simplifying the way to use vmaf](https://gdavila.github.io/broadcast/Vmaf/Vmaf/)